# Select records with a MAX(Date) but don't get distinct return

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I am joining to tables and my code look like as follow:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM (
  SELECT ABC.StockCode
    ,ABC.Supplier
    ,ABC.Price
    ,MAX(ABC.OrigReceiptDate) ReceiptDate
  FROM (
    SELECT GRND.StockCode
      ,GRND.Supplier
      ,OrigReceiptDate
      ,(GRND.OrigGrnValue / GRND.QtyReceived) AS Price
    FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[GrnDetails] GRND
    WHERE QtyReceived > 0
    ) ABC
  GROUP BY ABC.StockCode
    ,ABC.Supplier
    ,ABC.Price
  ) P
WHERE P.StockCode IN (
    SELECT StockCode
    FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[InvMaster]
    )
ORDER BY P.StockCode
  ,P.Price
```

The result set however is:

[image]

My problem here is i need to obtain the stock code and its price that was purchased latest...but I get duplicate values due to the prices that differs any idea to help out a blonde>

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
      ABC.StockCode, 
      ABC.Supplier, 
      ABC.Price,
      ABC.OrigReceiptDate AS ReceiptDate, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ABC.Supplier
                        ORDER BY ABC.OrigReceiptDate DESC) AS RN 
    FROM
    (
       SELECT GRND.StockCode, GRND.Supplier,OrigReceiptDate, 
         (GRND.OrigGrnValue /GRND.QtyReceived) as Price
       FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[GrnDetails] GRND
       Where QtyReceived > 0
    ) AS ABC 
    INNER JOIN [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[InvMaster] AS m 
            ON ABC.StockCode = m.StockCode
)
SELECT 
  StockCode, 
  Supplier, 
  Price,
  ReceiptDate
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

This should give you the stock code and its price that was purchased latest for each supplier.

Comment: You RowNumber part do not create unique row numbers i have seen so i have multiple RN columsn with the same number dont know if that is suppose to happen...

Comment: @user1546143, Yes, this because of the `PARTITION BY ABC.Supplier` each supplier has its sequence depending on the ordering of date, for example the supplier 0203004 will have from 1 to n , then `0204260` will have from 1 to n ordering by date descending the the filter `WHERE RN = 1` will eliminate all and leave the first on which is for the max date. Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi Yes i have but, my resulst with duplicates return about 3600 records and yours return only 154, but in my return list i have stock codes you dont...

Comment: @user1546143 You might want to `partition by` stock code, not supplier.

Comment: @user1546143 - Can you please post some sample data and the desired output, and please not images to work on easily, this will be very helpful.

Comment: StockCode Supplier Price ReceiptDate
10101001 204814 95.5 1/7/2013
1011 200041 0.82 3/28/2013
1182 203004 35.11 5/31/2013
1184 203004 45.6 7/11/2013
1319 200380 1215 5/20/2013
1490 200116 93 2/5/2013
1493 203004 288.02 5/16/2013
1494 204260 606.26 5/15/2013
1494 204260 626.78 3/7/2013
1496 203004 1267.9 5/23/2013
1623 200625 116.8 5/16/2013
1623 205012 329.05 7/11/2013

Comment: So from this sample date e,g  There should only be 1 record return the stock code with the highest date                                                               20 200178 97.03           3/7/2013
20 200178 99.38933333 3/26/2013
20 200178 116.92           4/29/2013
20 200178 125.08           7/2/2013
20 200178 147.16           7/23/2013

Comment: @user1546143 - Where does the `20` and the `200178` come from? I don't see them in the sample data? Please post them in the original post not in the comment, you can also make a demo in [**this site**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9e07).

Comment: Did you solve your problem using any of the proposed solutions? (I just updated mine, there was an error)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this form of query is more understandable and can be easily maintained:

```
;WITH ABC AS (
  SELECT 
    GRND.StockCode,
    GRND.Supplier,
    OrigReceiptDate,
    Price = (GRND.OrigGrnValue / GRND.QtyReceived),
  FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[GrnDetails] GRND
  WHERE QtyReceived > 0
),
P AS (
  SELECT 
    ABC1.StockCode,
    lastOne.Supplier,
    lastOne.Price,
    ReceiptDate = lastOne.OrigReceiptDate
  FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT StockCode FROM ABC) ABC1
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT TOP 1
        Supplier,
        Price,
        OrigReceiptDate
      FROM ABC
      WHERE StockCode = ABC1.StockCode
      ORDER BY OrigReceiptDate DESC
    ) lastOne
)
SELECT *
FROM P
WHERE 
  StockCode IN (
    SELECT StockCode
    FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[InvMaster])
ORDER BY 
  StockCode,
  Price
```

Comment: Thx alot for the fast replies @Mahmoud Gamal this works 100 but for some reason it left out ALOT of stock codes..My result with duplicate return about 3600 records and yours return only 154, but in my return list i have stock code you dont... @ Ozren it complains that olumn 'lastOne.Supplier' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Guess it needs that column in one of the group by clasuses

Answer (score 0):

One more option with operator EXISTS and correlated subquery in WHERE clause

```
SELECT P.*
FROM (
      SELECT GRND.StockCode, GRND.Supplier, GRND.OrigReceiptDate, (GRND.OrigGrnValue / GRND.QtyReceived) AS Price
      FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[GrnDetails] AS GRND
      WHERE QtyReceived > 0      
      ) P
WHERE P.StockCode IN (
                      SELECT StockCode
                      FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[InvMaster]
                      )
  AND EXISTS(
             SELECT 1
             FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[GrnDetails] AS GRND2
             WHERE GRND.StockCode = GRND2.StockCode
               AND GRND.Supplier = GRND2.Supplier
             HAVING MAX(GRND2.OrigReceiptDate) = GRND.OrigReceiptDate
             )
ORDER BY P.StockCode, P.Price
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM( SELECT  StockCode,
              Supplier,
              OrigGrnValue/QtyReceived) AS Price,
              OrigReceiptDate AS ReceiptDate
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode, Supplier, OrigGrnValue/QtyReceived ORDER BY OrigReceiptDate DESC) as rown
      FROM GrnDetails
      WHERE QtyReceived > 0 ) a
WHERE a.rown = 1
AND a.StockCode EXISTS (SELECT StockCode
                        FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[InvMaster] m
                        WHERE m.StockCode = a.StockCode)
ORDER BY a.StockCode,
         a.Price
```